# Method does not override method from its superclass

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Пытаюсь понять в чем ошибка и на что ругается Android Studio в переопределении метода интерфейса, от которого имплементируюсь в данном классе.

```
public class AddNoteActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements saveClickable{

    private EditText editTextTitle;
    private EditText editTextDescription;
    private Spinner spinnerDaysOfWeek;
    private RadioGroup radioGroupPriority;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_add_note);
        editTextTitle = findViewById(R.id.editTextTitle);
        editTextDescription = findViewById(R.id.editTextDescription);
        spinnerDaysOfWeek = findViewById(R.id.spinnerDaysOFWeek);
        radioGroupPriority = findViewById(R.id.radioGroupPriority);
    }

    @Override // в этом месте ругается Anroid Studio "Method does not override method from its superclass"
    public void onClickSaveNote(View view) {
        String title = editTextTitle.getText().toString().trim();
        String description = editTextDescription.getText().toString().trim();
        String dayOfWeek = spinnerDaysOfWeek.getSelectedItem().toString();
        int radioButtonId = radioGroupPriority.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
        RadioButton radioButton = findViewById(radioButtonId);
        int priority = Integer.parseInt(radioButton.getText().toString());
        Note note = new Note(title, description, dayOfWeek, priority);
        MainActivity.notes.add(note);
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

Интерфейс от которого имплементируюсь:

```
package com.demo.notes;

public interface saveClickable {
    public void onClickSaveNote();
}
```

Спасибо!

Comment: У интерфейса `public void onClickSaveNote();` не имеет входного параметра. Либо добавьте параметр `View view` в интерфейсе, либо удалите в реализации.

Comment: @Alex_Skvortsov, большое Вам спасибо!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ругается потому что сигнатуры методов не совпадают - в интерфейсе нет параметра `View`.
Сигнатура метода - это имя и типы параметров, при чём последовательность параметров тоже имеет значение.
Для переопределения/реализации метода необходимо объявить метод с тем же именем и набором параметров.

Если совпадает только имя - это называется перегрузкой и используется только для лучшего понимания того, что методы делают одно и тоже, но из разных входных данных.
Но технически перегруженные методы никак не связаны между собой.